# Extract nested information from the runOutput parameter of databricks activity

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have an ADF pipeline that contains a Databricks activity. The runOutput of this activity is as follows:

```
"runOutput": {
    "index": {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 0,
        "2": 1
    },
    "t0": {
        "0": "2030-04-26 11:50:30.594",
        "1": "2030-04-26 11:50:30.594",
        "2": "2030-04-26 11:50:30.594"
    },
    "t1": {
        "0": "2030-04-26 11:55:30.594",
        "1": "2030-04-26 11:55:30.594",
        "2": "2030-04-26 11:55:30.594"
    },
    "name": {
        "0": "all",
        "1": "Alt",
        "2": "Ass"
    },
    "CA": {
        "0": 6710065.65,
        "1": 257580.69,
        "2": 171109.65
    },
    "nb_ligne": {
        "0": 170506,
        "1": 6500403,
        "2": 4142539
    },
    "nb_tickets": {
        "0": 444766,
        "1": 164764,
        "2": 111471
    },
    "CAparPanier": {
        "0": 145.04,
        "1": 1745.48,
        "2": 145.41
    },
    "CAparLigne": {
        "0": 23.94,
        "1": 35.96,
        "2": 74.14
    },
    "ligneParPanier": {
        "0": 23.82,
        "1": 34.91,
        "2": 32.73
    }
}
```

My goal is to extract all the values for each key (index, t0, t1, name, CA, etc.) and append each set of value to an array, (ex: CA=[6710065.65,257580.69,171109.65]).

for more details:
I can access statically to each value of this output for example to get the first value of CA this is the corresponding expression:

```
@activity('landing to raw mailing').output.runOutput.CA['0']
```

but i need dynamic solution.

To achieve this, I am considering two scenarios:

1. The first scenario involves using a ForEach activity to loop through each key in the runOutput object. Within this activity, I would use a pipeline to invoke another ForEach activity to extract all the values for each key and append every one to an array using an Append Variable activity.
2. The second scenario involves storing the runOutput of the Databricks activity in a JSON file. I would then parse the JSON file to extract the desired data.

However, I am unsure of how to implement the two scenarios.
example for the first scenario the expression of the foreach return 1 item (i must got 10). So how can i loop on each key?
this is the foreach expression:

```
@array(activity('landing to raw mailing').output['runOutput'])
```

Comment: you want values of all the keys in a single array or make a key value JSON where keys are above JSON keys and values are the array of respective keys values from the above JSON?

Comment: As output i need 10 arrays: (tindex_array, 0_array, t1_array, name_array, CA_array, nb_ligne_array, nb_tickets_array, CAparPanier_array, CAparLigne_array,  ligneParPanier _array)
Exemple of array:
CA=[6710065.65,257580.69,171109.65]

Comment: it doesn't matter the type of the content, it can be string
example: CA=["6710065.65", "257580.69" ,"171109.65"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement using your 1st method like below which will only work in this case.

I took the above JSON from lookup. For you, it will be databricks notebook `runOutout`JSON.

- Then, I converted the JSON into string and took substring by skipping first `{`.

  [image]
- Then I have used split on the above string with `"},"`.
  [image]
- Give this array to ForEach and inside ForEach, get the key and append to an array.
- After that, call another pipeline using Execute pipeline activity and pass the array using the key from the JSON as an array parameter to the child pipeline.
  [image]
- In Child pipeline, create an array variable with values `["0","1","1"]` and pass this to a ForEach.
- Inside that ForEach, append the values of the array(array of key) to an array variable using the above keys.
  [image]
- Outside the ForEach, use a **set variable return** to return the array from child to parent pipeline.
- Now, in the parent pipeline ForEach activity, concat the array with key to build a key value pair where key is our key and value will be the array of it.

After concatenation, it will give a string and outside ForEach, add `{` and `}` to it.

**Result**:

[image]

Variables in ADF do not support of object type currently. So, I am showing the output as string type here. When using it, you can convert it to object using `json()` function.

You can see the key value pair above. you can access the array by the keys list(give this to ForEach) we got from the append variable inside first ForEach.

**My Parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Jsongen2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "convert json to string",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "jsonasstring",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@substring(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),1,sub(length(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])),1))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "split string to array",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "convert json to string",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "splitarray",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@split(variables('jsonasstring'),'},')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "split string to array",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('splitarray')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "keys",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(split(item(),':')[0],'\"','')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Append variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "child",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "json": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][replace(split(item(),':')[0],'\"','')]",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "concat to temp",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@concat(variables('final_string'),'\"',replace(split(item(),':')[0],'\"',''),'\":',activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.myarr,',')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "assign temp to final_str",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "concat to temp",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "final_string",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final_json",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@concat('{',variables('final_string'),substring(variables('final_string'),0,sub(length(variables('final_string')),1)),'}')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "jsonasstring": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "splitarray": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "keys": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "final_string": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final_json": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Child Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('numbers')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.json[item()]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "numbers",
                    "value": [
                        "0",
                        "1",
                        "2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "return",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "myarr",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@variables('arr')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "json": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "numbers": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```